# What are the Perl equivalents of return,break and continue keywords in php?

Tags: php, perl

I am getting this error when I use this code

```
if($DirEnt == "." || $DirEnt == "..") continue;

if($DirEnt == "default" && $ignore_default) continue;
```

error:-

```
syntax error at test.pl line 35, near ")  continue"

syntax error at test.pl line 38, near ") continue"
```

Comment: SO is not a manual. Try here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops

Comment: "closed as too localized" - wrong. I just landed here from Google because I don't know PERL either. And reading through the PERL docs referenced provided by Axeman has only confused me.

Answer (score 7):

They are: [`return`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/return.html), [`last`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html), and [`next`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/next.html).

And they can be done like this:

```
next if $DirEnt =~ /^[.]{1,2}$/;
last if $DirEnt eq 'LastEntry!!';
```

For completeness sake

- There's also a way to start the loop over again: [`redo`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/redo.html).
- All of these take a label:

  ```
  OUTER: while ( <$in1> ) { 
      ...
      while ( <$in2> ) { 
          ....
          redo OUTER if i_feel_like_it( $_ );
      }
  }
  ```
- Finally, [`continue`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/continue.html) doesn't work like it does in the C/Java family. It is used to

  1. Conduct bookkeeping in between iterations of loops, this is a continue *block* (see the link).
  2. To switch to the next matching case in the recent switch structure, called given-when blocks. All condition blocks in a Perl switch block are like C-`case` blocks that have a `break` at the end--except for those with a `continue`, which allows the switch to find *other cases* it matches (it doesn't just drop through like in C and Java).

For all this and the various permutations, see [`perldoc perlsyn`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html). [perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org/) is a better place to learn about this stuff, not Stackoverflow.

Comment: And for completeness: `redo`.  Worth mentioning: `continue` has a different meaning, but still deals with loops.  `perldoc perlsyn`.